# The type or namespace name 'ResponseType' could not be found. Does not exist in System.Web.HTTP

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to create a webapi. And I am getting the above error. I have tried to install the latest and greatest. See below. But it does not have the attribute/property etc of ResponseType in it. I have System.Web.Http.Description listed. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 <Reference Include="System.Web.Http, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.0.0\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

And the SubmissionController:

```
using System.Web.Http.Description;

[EnableCors(origins: "", headers: "", methods: "*")]
public class SubmissionController : ApiController 
{ 
    [Queryable] 
    [ResponseType(typeof(Submission))] 
    <!--error here --> 
    public IQueryable<Submission> Get(ODataQueryOptions opts) 
    { 
        ----code is in here---- 
    }
}
```

Here is my package.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="elmah" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="elmah.corelibrary" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Elmah.MVC" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.6.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.6.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Moq" version="4.2.1402.2112" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="RhinoMocks" version="3.6.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="structuremap" version="3.0.3.116" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="STTI.DataService.Library.Server" version="1.1.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="STTI.Elmah.Avectra" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="STTI.Elmah.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="STTI.netForum.Dependencies" version="1.1.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="STTI.Survey.API.Library" version="1.1.1.6-Development" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.6.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="TaskHelpers.Sources" version="0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebApiContrib" version="0.9.14.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp" version="3.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebApiContrib.IoC.StructureMap" version="0.9.5.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebApiContrib.Testing" version="0.7.18.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: `ApiDescription` class has no `ResponseType` property. [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.description.apidescription(v=vs.118).aspx). Did you mean `ResponseDescription`?

Comment: Are you trying to tag your controller methods with a `ResponseTypeAttribute`? Also, can you post what is in your packages.config file and web.config files, along with some of your code? That would help us out a bit.

Comment: I think that you must provide some code to us in order to help you. The `[ResponseType]` attribute is part of the `System.Web.Http.Description` namespace. If you include this namespace and the attribute is correctly defined, then the exception must gone.

Comment: All the web pages out there are pointing me in this direction..to get the decorators for web api to work. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.description.responsetypeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx .Error is highlighting lines like this: [ResponseType(typeof(Submission))]

Comment: Post the code in your question please. Also, can you please show us what is in your packages.config file?

Comment: It is the issue between versions of system.web.http as 4.0, I manually changed from 4.0 to 5.1. But I guess the problem for me is the nu-get is not removing the 4.0 and changing to 5.0. I will mark this as 'fixed'. But thanks for taking the time to read it, and respond.

Comment: I just created a new project and by default the `System.Web.Http` version it's putting in is 4.0.30319, that's what I've always used.

Answer (score 1):

[reinstall command and](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/reinstalling-packages)
[the dangers of...](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/reinstalling-packages)

update-package -reinstall

...but it worked for me.